# Laravel Paginate not working with specific model or table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Paginate not working for specific model. with all Models, paginate is working fine except one specific model. Also tried with query builder.

```
$doubts = DB::table('users')->paginate(10);
  dd($doubts->count());
```

//output: 10

```
$doubts = DB::table('doubts')->paginate();
  dd($doubts->count());
```

//output: 0

```
$doubts = DB::table('doubts')->get();
  dd($doubts->count());
```

//output: 8

Don't know what am I missing here. Please help.

Comment: Hey @Yogesh.galav, the number parameter of paginate method isn't required? Probably missing put a number of items perpage there?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I think you have to put
How many results you want to show per page
So if you want 8
Then  I think it should be something like this

$doubts = DB::table('doubts')->paginate(8);
dd($doubts->count());

And if you are using pages Number under your data then you might need the query builder.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass number argument inside paginate function.
Look at laravel pagination [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results)

And make sure that `DB::table('doubts')`
Is returning collection

Answer (score 0):

I thing you must add parameter in paginate(), to show how much data that show per page. You can read documentation in : https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#cursor-pagination
because you are not add parameter in paginate, it means not data that show every page.

```
$doubts = DB::table('doubts')->paginate(10);
```